# How can I send health status of my Angular app to Akamai?

Tags: angular, akamai

I have an Angular app and I'm using the Akamai CDN. What's the best way to send the health status (200, 500, etc.) to Akamai so that if it doesn't return a 200 code, Akamai knows to switch clusters?

Answer (score 1):

If your domain is setup in Akamai, then you could use Akamai's [Global traffic manager (GTM)](https://www.akamai.com/products/global-traffic-management) to route traffic to your angular application. If you have more than 2 clusters, then you could setup a "Weighted Random Load Balancing" property in GTM, which will allow you to assign weights for your clusters. Each of your cluster will be monitored using a "*Liveness test*", which will allow for failover in the instance one of your cluster starts giving a bad health response.